# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when the XPath expression is null

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm testing with the selenium webdriver, and getting an error. I have set the Ro.properties file and put all locator in properties file.

Below is the code that I am using, can anyone please help me out?

```
public class usePropertiesFile {
    private WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop = new Properties();
    public static FileInputStream fip = null;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://gmail.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }
    @AfterTest
    public void Teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    @Test
    public void testPropFile() throws Exception {
              fip = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\src\\config\\RO.properties");
        prop.load(fip);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("login_use"))).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("login_use"))).sendKeys("userid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `.properties` file (located at `C:\Users\src\config\RO.properties`), the property `login_use` is not set.

In other words, you test program is finding the `properties` file (otherwise it'd throw a file not found exception), but is not finding a property with `login_use` name.

Try adding after `prop.load(fip);`:

```
System.out.println("Value of 'login_use': "+prop.getProperty("login_use"));
```

It will probably print `null`.

Add this line to your `RO.properties`:

```
login_use=//input[@name\='Email']
```

It should now get `//input[@name\='Email']` (instead of `null`) as value (change the expression to what you want, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the Illegal Argument error because your Ro.Properties file is not present the path you have declared in the script.

First of all, copy the updated Ro.properties file in the execution folder path (if it is not present). Then verify the attributes used properly assigned or not.

Execute the script, it should work.